# server.execute control events from firing script

Tags: asp.net

I am using `server.execute` in my `default.aspx` to call `default2.aspx` is it possible to fire the `default2.aspx` page and control events from `default.aspx`?

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the architecture of your web application while you have to use such a thing. Take a deeper look at the master pages and try to use the ASP.NET the way it was designed to use.